# Printing transplant source changeset hash

Tags: mercurial, transplant, hg-log

We've transplanted a changeset from another repository to the current one. It seems to us that the transplant extensions stores the original changset hash in an extra field which can be shown with `hg log --debug`, like:

```
changeset:   720:092506
tag:         tip
parent:      ...
parent:      ...
manifest:    ...
user:        ...
date:        ...
files:       ...
extra:       branch=default
extra:       transplant_source=\xe3>\xa7py\xff\xcda\x93d\xde\xa5\xb5\xa6\xf7\xed\xc0\x16\x82\xa3
description:
Bugfix, ...
```

Here the original changset hash (`transplant_source`) is not too readable and usable.
How can we print the `transplant_source` in a readable format with `hg log` command?

I've played with [`ifeq` and the list operator](http://www.selenic.com/hg/help/templates) without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disgusting, and doesn't answer the question, but seems to work (Python 2): :)

`hg log --debug | python -c "import sys, re; x=re.compile(r'^extra:\\s+transplant_source='); print '\\n'.join([l.split('=',1)[0]+'='+eval('\"'+l.split('=',1)[1].strip()+'\"').encode('hex') if x.match(l) else l.rstrip('\\n') for l in sys.stdin])"`

Comment: OMG :)) I have to check it now.

Comment: It works, thanks! I guess I'll wait a few days, somebody might have a simpler solution.